# Show multi-configuration project details in list view

Tags: jenkins

We are running one of our test suites as a multi-configuration job with one axis, where each test subfolder is one value in that axis. (It's a little more complicated than that, but that's the gist of it.)

Basically our job looks something like this:

```
Tests (Matrix)
 - foo
 - bar
 - baz
```

What I want to do is display the current status of each configuration as a simple list view. For instance like so:

```
Tests (Matrix) >> foo  (passed)
Tests (Matrix) >> bar  (failed)
Tests (Matrix) >> baz  (passed)
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

I've tried the [View Job Filters](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/View+Job+Filters) plugin and thought selecting the matrix project with the *Recurse in subfolders* option set would do the trick, but to no avail.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I edited in some of my progress, is this along the lines of your idea too?

Comment: I think i nailed all obvious issues on the plugin extension. My plan is to checkstyle the code and issue a pull request, hovever any feedback is appreciated (best on github).

Answer (score 2):

This wont be so easy. The normal `ListView` accepts only jobs, and a matrix-job doesn't produce jobs, we get *builds*.

So, what we really need would be a list of recent builds, filtered in a way to only show the most recent build of each matrix combination.

The [Dashboard View Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dashboard+View) has a widget that displays recent builds of a job (see linked image), however it shows only the toplevel job. *Maybe* it can be extended to find out and show the child builds of a matrix-job instead, and filter them for the most recent build.

[image]

If i find time i will look into this, i really could use this functionality too..

### Edit

Working on extending the *Jobs Grid* portlet. It can be found on [my github](https://github.com/DominikGebhart/dashboard-view-plugin), its WIP though.

[image]

[image]

Download link for the installable hpi, udated 20/05/2016: [dashboard-view.hpi 2.9.10-SNAPSHOT](https://www.dropbox.com/s/prp2i7mez95edzr/dashboard-view.hpi).

Comment: Thank you, that would be much appreciated. It's a little odd that apparently no one has run into this issue yet, at least my Google search didn't turn up anything.

Comment: Indeed odd, it would also be *very* useful to be able to display matrix jobs that way.

Comment: I don't see the "Filtered Jobs Grid" option, only the regular "Jobs Grid". Is there an additional plugin I need to install?

Comment: Yes, its an extended version i am working on. Ill put it on github when im done.

Comment: Awesome! let me know when it's there so I can award you the bounty.

Comment: I added it to github, i included the `dashboard-view.hpi` which can be installed via `Plugin Manager > Advanced > Upload plugin`, however keep in mind its by no means finished nor really tested yet, its work-in-progress. Should be able to download it by selecting it, its inside `target` folder, and choosing *raw*, or this [direct link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DominikGebhart/dashboard-view-plugin/master/target/dashboard-view.hpi).

Comment: Removed the binary from github to allow a PR, latest plugin binary can be downloaded from [this dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d7q2gkbblhdnqc9/dashboard-view.hpi?dl=0)

Comment: Was this ever merged? I don't see your Filtered Jobs Grid in the latest release (May 17th).

Comment: Hi, has this improvement been merged to the mainstream plugin ?

Comment: No, this was not merged. Not sure about its use now, best practice is to use pipeline as code, which does not support matrix jobs.